# Find all queries which returns a particular text in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I am using sql server 2012. I want to search all the queries in all databases of a server which returns this text ("ca040"). I am using SQL Server Profiler with filtered TextData.

But it is not showing any results. Have I gone for the correct approach?

Comment: Profiler can show you whether the query itself contains a specified string, but not whether the results contain it.   I know of no way to get that information.

Comment: Yes. There is a search query which contains this string.

Comment: Meaning this value is hardcoded in the query or it is a parameter? Are you looking for the queries that have this value or the rows in tables that have this value?

Comment: Did you put wildcard characters around the string you are searching for in the profiler trace?:     "%ca040%"

Comment: I am looking for the queries which has this value in a condition (where booking = 'ca040').